# How to change/add dependencies in Gradle 3?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

The following lines are in a Gradle plugin:

```
project.configurations.compile.incoming.resolutionResult.allComponents.findAll { ..}
//...
Dependency dependency = project.dependencies.add('packaged', dependencyDescription)
```

Applying this plugin works in Gradle 2, but fails in Gradle 3 with:

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'test']
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':my-project'.
>
> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':my-project:packaged' after it has been included in
> dependency resolution.

Removing the 2nd line, the error disappears in Gradle 3.
Now I would like to know the time & place which is valid in Gradle 3 to update the configuration. Reading the Gradle 3 manual i could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like incoming.resolutionResult from  the line

```
project.configurations.compile.incoming.resolutionResult.allComponents.findAll {..}
```

is triggering dependency resolution so any modification to the dependencies after that causes the error.

The resolution can be eliminated by doing a copy and reading from it instead.

```
project.configurations.compile.copyRecursive().incoming.resolutionResult.allComponents.findAll {..}
```